# How can I implement jQuery in my Kotlin project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kotlin

I'm trying to use the lib jquery from kotlin js:

```
jq("root").html("ddddddd")
```

But he is deprecated and does not work

```
Warning:(8, 9) Kotlin: 'jq(String): JQuery' is deprecated. JQuery is going to be removed from the standard library
```

Is there any other alternative to install jquery and how?

Answer (score 0):

Use annotations to import JQUERY functions. JQ has to be loaded before your Kotlin-JS module!

```
@JsName("$")
@JsNonModule
@JsModule("jquery")
external fun jq(id: String): dynamic
```

You may then use JQUERY as e.g.

```
jq("#sidebar, #content").toggleClass("active")
```

"dynamic" does the trick here. It suppresses the compilers type check allowing to call object methods without trouble.
Define more overload functions if needed.